# Replace list value in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary. For objects that have the value `['FAIL', 'PASS']`, I'd like to replace it with `'PASS'` only.

```
Dict = [('Main Menu-046', ['PASS']), ('Main Menu-047', ['FAIL']), ('Main Menu-044', ['FAIL', 'PASS']), ('Main Menu-045', ['PASS']), ('Main Menu-042', ['FAIL', 'PASS']), ('Main Menu-043', ['FAIL'])
```

I tried the following:

```
if "FAIL" in [x for v in Dict.values() for x in v]: ## if true
    Dict.values == "PASS"
```

Comment: Currently Dict is a list of tuples and not a dictionary

Comment: There is a bracket missing in the first snippet. However, your `Dict` looks like a list of `tuple`s. Besides you should not name a variable as a DataType (`Dict` is a python datatype). So do you have a dictionary or a list of tuples?

Comment: Actually I have a list that was parsed from a csv file. I did treat other duplication and put it in a dic as follows

Comment: Dict = {}
    for Data in mylist:
#        print Data[0]
        Dict.setdefault(Data[0], []).append(Data[1])

  print [(key, values) for key, values in Dict.items()]

    if "FAIL" in [x for v in Dict.values() for x in v]:
        Dict.values == "PASS"

Comment: @MoeSiddig so edit your question and explain what exactly you want

Comment: @MoeSiddig If you could include that in an edit to your post instead of comments where you can't properly format it, [that'd be great](https://imgflip.com/s/meme/That-Would-Be-Great.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to replace `['FAIL', 'PASS']` with `['PASS']`

```
processed_list = [(x[0], ["PASS"] if "PASS" in x[1] else x[1]) for x in Dict]
```

Results in:

```
[('Main Menu-046', ['PASS']),
 ('Main Menu-047', ['FAIL']),
 ('Main Menu-044', ['PASS']),
 ('Main Menu-045', ['PASS']),
 ('Main Menu-042', ['PASS']),
 ('Main Menu-043', ['FAIL'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use a dict but a list of pair `(Main, [PASS/FAIL])`

If you want a dictionary, you can create it by `d = { key:value, key:value ... }` or by `d = dict()` and add item by simply `d['newkey'] = value`

Plus, if you wish, you can apply default value like this :

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda : defaultvalue)
```

When you'll have your dict, try a loop like:

```
for key in d.keys():
  if d[key] == 'FAIL': # or if 'FAIL' in d[key] if d[key] is a list like ['FAIL']
    d[key] = 'PASS' # or == ? why a boolean without condition or return ?
```